# How to autofill fields in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make the `password` of the user the same as the `user id`. What i don't want is to copy and paste the `user id` from the `user id` field into the `password` field. Instead, what i want to achieve is that as soon as i enter the `user id`, the same values get input into the `password` field. how can i achieve this? Below is my code:

**Blade :**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">Add New User</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            {!! Form::open(['action'=>'AccountsController@store', 'method'=>'POST']) !!}
                            <div class="row form-group justify-content-center">
                                {{Form::label('name','Name',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    {{Form::text('name','',['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Name'])}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row form-group justify-content-center">
                                {{Form::label('email','Email',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    {{Form::text('email','',['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Email'])}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row form-group justify-content-center">
                                {{Form::label('userid','User I.D',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    {{Form::text('userid','',['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'User I.D'])}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row form-group justify-content-center">
                                {{Form::label('password','Password',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    {{Form::password('password',['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Password'])}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row form-group justify-content-center">
                                {{Form::label('cpassword','Confirm Password',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    {{Form::password('cpassword',['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Confrim Password'])}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row form-group justify-content-center">
                                {{Form::submit('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
                            </div>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**controller :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Account;
use App\User;

class AccountsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // $accounts = Account::all();
        $accounts = User::all();
        return view('accounts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('accounts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
            'userid'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required'
        ]);

        // $account = new Account;
        $account = new User;
        $account->name = $request->input('name');
        $account->email = $request->input('email');
        $account->userid= $request->input('userid');
        $account->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $account->save();

        return redirect('/accounts')->with('success', 'User has been successfully added!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**model :**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email','userid', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**database :**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('userid')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achive such a dynamic operation you need JavaScript and I suggest to use `JQuery` for this. [Here](https://jquery.com/) you can read more about it.

So first add JQuery to your project as described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp).

Then use this code to achieve your goal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#userid').on('change', function() {
        $('#password').val($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

The code will listen for changes of the `#userid` element and then insert the value of it into the `#password` element.

The code needs to be on the same page as your form is.

If you're using jquery for further stuff I suggest to add those scripts by using the stacks mechanism of blade. It's described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#stacks). In my opinion this would be a bit better than entering the code directly in your view.

Comment: so do i put the script in the section area or outside the section area?

Comment: You need to put it inside of the section area at the end just before the `@endsection`. Everything outside of any section areas will be ignored by blade.

Comment: I think i'm stuck on adding the jquery to my project. If it ain't too much to ask may you guide me through the process as i cant seem to understand the information from the link you sent. Where exactly do i add the jquery?

Comment: Add this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the header section of your page in the file `app.blade.php` in `/resources/views/layouts`.